# Eclipse - как добавить свои теги в редактор HTML?

Tags: ide, eclipse, html

Есть список своих тегов (которые потом естественно обрабатываются на сервере и выводятся как валидный HTML код), например:

```
<html>
<body>
...
    <Gallery type="grid" title="Галлерея" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

Как можно расширить функциональность редактора HTML так, чтобы:

1. Сделать подсветку в HTML коде своих тегов?
2. Сделать автодополнения (просто шаблоны не подходят), т.е. я ввожу "<Gallery ", нажимаю "Ctrl+Space" - в списке предлагаемых атрибутов для тега Gallery выводятся "type" и "title", я ввожу "<Gallery type=", нажимаю "Ctrl+Space" - в списке предлагаемых значений для атрибута type: "grid", "listview", "3d".

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1. Подсветка пользовательских тегов уже присутствует в новых версиях
2. Выбираем в меню команду Window-Preferences, в левом списке выбираем Web, HTML-files, Editor, Templates. Справа в окне появится список тегов, в который можно добавить свой, нажав кнопку "New". В диалоге создания можно также указать его свойства и другие параметры.